# How to disable column filters doing AND/OR logic in ag-grid v18

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Ag-Grid 18 came with some very nice features. One of them is: "Column filters now support AND/OR logic". But unfortunately I need to disable this feature and enable only the old one-condition logic. 
I could not find in the documentation how to do it and I would appreciate if someone could point me in the direction.

Thanks in advance,
Tal

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

From the documentation [Filter Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/18.0.0/javascript-grid-filter-number/)
You can use `filterParams` in column definition as below -

```
    filter:'agTextColumnFilter',
    filterParams: {
        suppressAndOrCondition: true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this
its working at my end,

```
const filterParams={
  filterOptions:[
    'startsWith',    
  ],
  suppressAndOrCondition: true
}

columnDefs=
{
headerName:'Full Name',
field: 'full_name',
filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
filterParams: filterParams
}
```